# Total number of count fetching issue in codeigniter3

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

The issue is im trying to fetch the total counts of institution and display the count, im using pagination. but i got the total count result as NaN(not a number) why? how can i fix this issue?

cotroller

```
public function pagination_institutions()
    {
        $data = $this->data;

        $limit = 2; // Number of records per page
        $offset = $this->uri->segment(3) !== false && is_numeric($this->uri->segment(3)) ? (int) $this->uri->segment(3) : 0; // Validate and convert to integer

        // Retrieve paginated institution data
        $result = $this->homepage->select_pagination_institutions($limit, $offset);
        $data['institution'] = $result['data']; // Updated institution data
        $data['pagination'] = $result['pagination'];

        // Other data retrieval for institutions
        $data["incat"] = $this->homepage->get_all_in_category();

        if ($this->session->userdata('client_id') == 19) {
            // $data['total_institutions'] = $this->homepage->get_total_institutions_for_client(19);
            $total_institutions = $this->homepage->get_total_institutions_for_client(19);
            $data['total_institutions'] = is_numeric($total_institutions) ? $total_institutions : 0;
            // $data['total_institutions'] = $total_institutions;
        }
        
        $this->template->views($data["theme"] . '/institutions', $data);
    }
```

Model

```
public function select_pagination_institutions($limit, $offset)
    {
        // $client_id = 17; // Assuming you want client_id to be 17
        $client_id = Client_Id;

        // Apply pagination
        $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
        $this->db->order_by('institution_id', 'DESC'); // Assuming 'institution_id' is the primary key

        // Set the conditions for the specific client_id
        $multiplewhere = array('sr_institution.status' => 1, 'sr_institution.client_id' => $client_id);

        $this->db->select('sr_institution.*,ci_institution_category.ic_name');
        $this->db->where($multiplewhere);

        // echo $this->db->last_query();

        $this->db->join('ci_institution_category', 'ci_institution_category.ic_id=sr_institution.category', 'left');

        // Fetch paginated data
        $result['data'] = $this->db->get('sr_institution')->result();

        // Count total rows with applied conditions
        $total_rows = $this->db->where($multiplewhere)->count_all_results('sr_institution');

        // Pagination Configuration
        $config['base_url'] = base_url('home/pagination_institutions');
        $config['total_rows'] = $total_rows;
        $config['per_page'] = $limit;
        $config['reuse_query_string'] = TRUE;


        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        // Set the pagination key in the result array
        $result['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
        

        return $result;
    }
public function get_total_institutions_for_client($client_id)
{
    // Set the conditions for the specific client_id
    $multiplewhere = array('status' => 1, 'client_id' => $client_id);

    try {
        // Count total rows with applied conditions for the specified client ID
        $total_rows = $this->db->where($multiplewhere)->count_all_results('sr_institution');
        return $total_rows;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        // Handle the exception, you may log it or return a default value
        error_log("Error counting total institutions: " . $e->getMessage());
        return 0; // Return 0 or handle the error appropriately
    }
}
```

View

```
<h2>
                                <span class="number">
                                    <?php
                                    echo is_numeric($total_institutions) ? $total_institutions : 'N/A';
                                    // Add debugging here to see the actual type of $total_institutions
                                    var_dump($total_institutions);
                                    ?>
                                </span>+
                            </h2>
```

The issue is im trying to fetch the total counts of institution and display the count, im using pagination. but i got the total count result as NaN(not a number) why? how can i fix this issue?

Comment: Do you have any proof if the cookie is 19?  If not then `$total_institutions` is undefined.